# Arguments in Array list and pass to new function? C

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible to put all the arguments in a array list and pass to new function? How would I start working that?

For example:

```
int arr(char *argv[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //how do I start? Run the for-loop to get all the arguments from the command line. Then how do I pass to arr function.
}

int arr(char *argv[]){
    //return printing out all the arguments. 
}
```

How would I get all the arguments from command line to arr function? Examples would be great. I am just having trouble figuring out how to get all the arguments to new function.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean -- are you saying is it possible to pass an array to a function? If so, then yes, it's possible. Just give the array name to the function. So in your case, `arr(argv);`

Comment: `argv` **is** all of the arguments from the command line. You don't need a for loop to get them. Just pass it directly to `arr()` with `arr(argv)`.

Comment: @jackarms quick question, what does this means? ` warning: implicit declaration of function 'arr'`

Comment: @Salman2013 It was used before the function 'arr' is declared. So that has been implicitly declared.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY How do I get rid of that warning?

Comment: @Salman2013 you do not have it if you have put the prototype declaration, as in the example here (`int arr(char *argv[]);`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arr(char *argv[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    arr(argv+1);
    return 0;
}

int arr(char *argv[]){
    while(*argv)
        puts(*argv++);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Notice that this works because it is specified (at least on Posix systems, and perhaps in C99) that `main`'s `argv` argument has `argc+1` elements the last being `NULL`. This is not necessarily true for other arrays of strings (e.g. the ones built in your program). So in practice, functions processing arrays also need their dimension!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  yes i know. Was estimated to be such a specification because it is not specified function `arr`.